# What class members do Throwable and Exception have in the D programming language?

Tags: exception, d, nested-exceptions

I'm particularly interested, how I can produce nested exception and how I can access those afterwards when I handle them. A link to some documentation would be appreciated. I have already tried to find it on the D website. No success though. I'm particularly interested in D2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>`Throwable` documentation: http://dlang.org/phobos/object.html#Throwable</s>

`Throwable` is implemented here: https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/druntime/blob/master/src/object_.d#L1304

`Exception`, which is currently not documented, is a subclass of `Throwable` with no new fields or methods.

`Error`, which is currently also not documented, is a subclass of `Throwable` with one new field: `bypassedException`, which is documented as following:

> The first Exception which was bypassed when this Error was thrown, or null if no Exceptions were pending.

Comment: What does it mean, that an exception is bypassed? And what does 'pending' mean in this context? Does it mean a caught exception that is 'forgotten' because an other exception is thrown in the catch-clause?

Comment: I believe it is related to `try..finally` and `scope(exit/failure)` blocks, but don't quote me on it. This area does need more documentation.